# Parsing JSon column value

Tags: json, dictionary, hive

I am trying to parse a json column from a table called Json_table which has 2 different types of elements,

```
keyfield  |  json_column | SomeotherField1 | SomeotherField2
----------------------------------------------------------------
keyfield1, | {"jField1":"Value1", ..."jField10":"Value10", "MapField":[{"Key": "key1", "Value":"Keyvalue1"}, {"Key": "key2", "Value":"Keyvalue2"}] | someothervalue | someothervalue
```

Using get_json_object function I can easily reach to jField1 to jField10 and MapField. But I dont know how i can parse MapField into further separate columns.

```
SELECT keyfield, get_json_object(json_column, '$.jField1') as jField1, get_json_object(json_column, '$.jField2') as jField2
FROM Json_table
```

I need to write query that would provide me results like this

```
Select Keyfield, jField1, jField2, .. , jField10, Key1, Key2 From Json_table
result as:

keyfield1 | Value1 | ... | Value10 | Keyvalue1 | Keyvalue2
```

I want to get all individual elements from within "Mapfield" part.

Comment: I have this table in Hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `MapField` array by indexes, **`$.MapField[0].Value,
$.MapField[1].Value`**

```
with cte as (
select string('{"jField1":"Value1","jField10":"Value10", "MapField":[{"Key": "key1", "Value":"Keyvalue1"}, {"Key": "key2", "Value":"Keyvalue2"}]}')as jsn_col) 
select get_json_object(jsn_col,'$.jField1')jField1,
get_json_object(jsn_col,'$.MapField[0].Value')key1,
get_json_object(jsn_col,'$.MapField[1].Value')key2 from cte;

+-------+---------+---------+
|jField1|key1     |key2     |
+-------+---------+---------+
|Value1 |Keyvalue1|Keyvalue2|
+-------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm.